# Angular CLI running ng serve webpack: failed to compile differ in casing and typescript compilation

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, webpack, angular-cli

I am running Angular 5 and I have installed both latest Angular CLI globally and locally but I am getting this error:

Currently this application is getting

```
ERROR in ./src/app/Assign-search/Assign-service.service.ts
Module build failed: Error: C:\dev\tom\my-test-app\src\app\Assign-search\Assign
service.service.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure
it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
at AngularCompilerPlugin.getCompiledFile (C:\dev\tom\my-test-app\node_modul
s\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:674:23)
at plugin.done.then (C:\dev\tom\my-test-app\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\s
c\loader.js:467:39)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

**Below is for reference only , solved this other application issue**

Issue below in an application was solved with :

> npm install pretty-checkbox

```
ERROR in multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./node_module
s/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css ./node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.
css ./node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/assets/style/picker.min.css ./node_modules/p
retty-checkbox/src/pretty-checkbox.scss ./src/styles.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\z244562\RxPACE-Web\RxPaceWeb\no
de_modules\pretty-checkbox\src\pretty-checkbox.scss' in 'C:\Users\z244562\RxPACE
-Web\RxPaceWeb'
```

I was reverted back to CLI 1.63 and got even more errors.  Seems like a wild goose chase as I been reading many conflicting answers on github

Comment: Ok - even with all the various changes to Angular CLI versions and npm and node versions  what fixed the above error was just `npm install pretty-checkbox`

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer.